# Yesod: how do you interpolate a route with a path piece?

Tags: path, interpolation, yesod, hamlet

If I have a route such as

```
/foo/#String FooR GET POST
```

How do I interpolate this path in a hamlet file (say, to post to?)

The following don't work:

```
<form method=post action=@{FooR} ... >
<form method=post action=@{FooR}someString ... >
<form method=post action=@{FooR}#someString ... >
<form method=post action=@{FooR}#{some_variable} ... >
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Got it. It's

```
<form method=post action=@{FooR some_variable} ... >
```